# maintain a list of exception types to ignore in the debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a frequent work scenario where I run my app in the debugger, with "break on exceptions" turned on, but run into a series of "garbage exceptions" that are thrown in framework code and caught/handled just fine within the framework.  These exceptions have nothing to do with the code I'm debugging.

Visual Studio allows me to ignore exceptions by type, but I have to do that one by one, by unchecking a box when they cause the debugger to break.  Once I have done that once for every exception type, I'm fine for a while, but I notice that whenever I do a `git clean -fdx`, Visual Studio forgets the list of exception types I want to ignore.

Is there a way to maintain a list of exceptions types to ignore in the debugger that I can check into `git`?

[I like doing a `git clean` every once in a while to start with a clean slate (and it also is sometimes the only way to get Visual Studio out of its confusion) and don't want to forego that practice.]

Comment: If you delete the file that VS uses to persist the exception list, then VS is going to forget your settings.  I believe it's in the `.suo` file buried deep in the `.vs` folder at the root of your solution.

Comment: a file which everyone says *not* to check into source control and which is not even human readable

Comment: Yeah, but getting rid of things that are not in source control is what `git clean -fdx` does best, no?

Comment: OK, but I want something that I *can* put in source control that will retain this list of exception types

Comment: But, that list is your list.  If two of us are working on a project, we are each going to have our own debugging style.  I don't want your preferences coming out of Git and squashing mine. That's why it's not in source control

Comment: I don't believe this is possible today, but it's a good idea. You can use the "Suggest a Feature" button in VS to request it be added. If you link your request here, I will make sure it is sent to the right team internally.